# Filtering or subsetting within a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, subset

I am trying to write a for loop to check if the relative abundances of observations based on grouped set of variables add up to 100. In the simplified example below, I want to check if all the relative abundance (RelAb) values associated with batch A1 add up to 100.

| Batch | Reads | RelAb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 28431 | 72.94 |
| A1 | 10549 | 27.06 |
| B1 | 19315 | 85.96 |
| B1 | 3155 | 14.04 |

If I were to check each batch one by one I would have to repeat the following code and change Batch to a different object each time.

```
test.batch <- data.batch %>%
  dplyr::filter(Batch == "A1")
sum(test.batch$RelAbByBatch)
```

I was able to get values of 100 for each batch I checked manually, but I didn't want to repeat the same line of code again and again.

So I tried writing a for loop:

```
Batches <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7")
for(i in Batches) {
  filtered.batch <- data.batch %>%
     dplyr::filter(Batch %in% Batches)
  print(sum(filtered.batch$RelAb))
```

However, the loop worked but the results from each variable did not add up to 100:

```
[1] 1100
[1] 1100
[1] 1100
[1] 1100
[1] 1100
[1] 1100
[1] 1100
[1] 1100
[1] 1100
[1] 1100
[1] 1100
```

Incidentally, the length of the Batches vector was 11 but I'm not sure how/why the correct result of 100 multiplied itself by 11.

I also tried subsetting instead of dplyr::filter but got the same result as above.

```
for(i in Batches) {
  filtered.batch <- data.batch[data.batch$Batch %in% Batches]
  print(sum(filtered.batch$Batch))
}
```

I'm sure a very simple solution would solve this issue (which is not even urgent because repeating a line of code 11 times isn't the biggest problem), but I'm very curious how this could be fixed so I can write correct code in the future. Thanks!

Comment: It's a typo kind of error : try `dplyr::filter(Batch %in% i)` instead of `dplyr::filter(Batch %in% Batches)`. Though you might take inspiration from the answers for a nicer way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table("Batch Reads   RelAb
A1  28431   72.94
A1  10549   27.06
B1  19315   85.96
B1  3155    14.04")


df %>%  
  summarise(sum = sum(RelAb), 
            threshold = sum(RelAb) >= 100, 
            .by = Batch)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  Batch   sum threshold
  <chr> <dbl> <lgl>         
1 A1      100 TRUE          
2 B1      100 TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you're looking for is the group_by clause and not a for loop.

In your example this would mean that you group by Batch and then sum up RelAb:

```r
library(dplyr)

sums <- data.batch %>%
  group_by(Batch) %>%
  summarize(sum_RelAb = sum(RelAb))
```